# Invert windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, desktop-customization

I want to position Windows 7 taskbar on the left side of the screen, but to revert it's default ordering: bottom left would be the Start button, then applications, then clock.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it is unless you find some software to do so, or ask Microsoft.

Comment: You could get ObjectDock let it hide Windows taskbar and then position the dock wherever you want and re-arrange the icons the way you want it.

Comment: Or you can use [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/Download/) to customize windows taskbar.